# How to fix error “ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python.” when trying to install py -m pip install google-assistant-sdk[samples]

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk

This is what i got when i ran the command `py -m pip install google-assistant-sdk[samples]` in cmd with administrator rights.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>py -m pip install google-assistant-sdk[samples]
```

Collecting google-assistant-sdk[samples]
  Using cached

> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/26/b405a0236ea5dd128f4b9c00806f4c457904309e1a6c60ec590e46cc19c4/google_assistant_sdk-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

```
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0 in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (0.4.1)

Requirement already satisfied: sounddevice<0.4,>=0.3.7; extra == "samples" in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (0.3.14)

Requirement already satisfied: futures<4,>=3.1.1; extra == "samples" in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (3.1.1)

Collecting google-assistant-grpc==0.2.1; extra == "samples"
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/5d/50dbb8197961acf8a4339e8950e0110159456c4ef48234751d1b5f2e919b/google_assistant_grpc-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Requirement already satisfied: pathlib2<3,>=2.3.0; extra == "samples" in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (2.3.5)

Requirement already satisfied: urllib3[secure]<2,>=1.21; extra == "samples" in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (1.25.6)

Requirement already satisfied: tenacity<5,>=4.1.0; extra == "samples" in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (4.12.0)

Requirement already satisfied: click<7,>=6.7; extra == "samples" in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (6.7)

Requirement already satisfied: google-auth in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (1.6.3)

Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (1.2.0)

Requirement already satisfied: CFFI>=1.0 in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from sounddevice<0.4,>=0.3.7; extra == "samples"->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (1.13.1)

Collecting googleapis-common-protos>=1.5.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/ee/e59e74ecac678a14d6abefb9054f0bbcb318a6452a30df3776f133886d7d/googleapis-common-protos-1.6.0.tar.gz

Collecting grpcio>=1.3.5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/60/40c4d2b61d9e4349bc89445deb8d04cc000b10a63446c42d311e0d21d127/grpcio-1.25.0.tar.gz

Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from pathlib2<3,>=2.3.0; extra == "samples"->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (1.12.0)

Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0.0; extra == "secure" in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from urllib3[secure]<2,>=1.21; extra == "samples"->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (2.8)

Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL>=0.14; extra == "secure" in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from urllib3[secure]<2,>=1.21; extra == "samples"->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (19.0.0)

Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=1.3.4; extra == "secure" in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from urllib3[secure]<2,>=1.21; extra == "samples"->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (2.8)

Requirement already satisfied: certifi; extra == "secure" in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from urllib3[secure]<2,>=1.21; extra == "samples"->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (2019.9.11)

Requirement already satisfied: cachetools>=2.0.0 in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from google-auth->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (3.1.1)

Requirement already satisfied: rsa>=3.1.4 in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from google-auth->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (4.0)

Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from google-auth->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (0.2.7)

Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.0.0 in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (2.22.0)

Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (3.1.0)

Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from CFFI>=1.0->sounddevice<0.4,>=0.3.7; extra == "samples"->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (2.19)

Collecting protobuf>=3.6.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/81/6d2dfdc9e8a377e151b1a481293dda7149c44c77428029645c978df22bc0/protobuf-3.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from rsa>=3.1.4->google-auth->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (0.4.7)

Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.0.0->requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (3.0.4)

Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.6.0->googleapis-common-protos>=1.5.2->google-assistant-grpc==0.2.1; extra == "samples"->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (41.2.0)

Installing collected packages: protobuf, googleapis-common-protos, grpcio, google-assistant-grpc, google-assistant-sdk

Running setup.py install for googleapis-common-protos ... done

Running setup.py install for grpcio ... error

 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\91999\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vnrp98y6\\grpcio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\91999\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vnrp98y6\\grpcio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\91999\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q8x2ji7q\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\91999\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vnrp98y6\grpcio\

 Complete output (66 lines):

Found cython-generated files...

running install

 running build

  running build_py

  running build_project_metadata

  creating python_build

  creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8

 creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_auth.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_channel.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_common.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_compression.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_grpcio_metadata.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_interceptor.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_plugin_wrapping.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_server.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc

 creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\implementations.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\interfaces.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\_client_adaptations.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\_metadata.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\_server_adaptations.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta

 creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\gevent.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\session_cache.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental

creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework

creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\_cython

copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_cython\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\_cython

 creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental\aio

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\aio\_channel.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental\aio

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\aio\_server.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental\aio

copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\aio\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental\aio

  creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\common

  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\common\cardinality.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\common

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\common\style.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\common

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\common\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\common

 creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation 

copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\abandonment.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation

  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\callable_util.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\future.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\logging_pool.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\stream.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation

  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\stream_util.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation

 creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces

  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces

 creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\base

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\base\base.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\base

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\base\utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\base

  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\base\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\base

 creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\face

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\face\face.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\face

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\face\utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\face

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\face\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\face

 creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\_cython\_cygrpc

  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_cython\_cygrpc\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\_cython\_cygrpc

 creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\_cython\_credentials

 copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_cython\_credentials\roots.pem -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\_cython\_credentials

running build_ext

error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

  ----------------------------------------

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\91999\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vnrp98y6\\grpcio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\91999\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vnrp98y6\\grpcio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\91999\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q8x2ji7q\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

pls help

Answer (score 1):

This problem [should be fixed now](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/21217). Try installing grpcio 1.26.0rc1.